# Apache include value of %{TIME_YEAR} variable in an HTTP response header

Tags: linux, apache2, http-headers

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
<If "%{IPV6} == 'off'">
  Header always set Attention "you are using still using IPV4 in %{TIME_YEAR}, please blahblah etc"
</If>
```

(please withhold commentary regarding the viability of communicating with humans through HTTP headers)

without the `%{TIME_YEAR}` it works fine but with it it gives an error `Unrecognized header format %,`

removing the % just results in the literal string `{TIME_YEAR}` being returned in the header

I've tried using `expr=%{TIME_YEAR}` or `%{env:TIME_YEAR}` but they error out as well

I've tried adding `PassEnv TIME_YEAR` prior but it gives an error `AH01506: PassEnv variable TIME_YEAR was undefined`

TIME_YEAR should be a valid variable according to this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

I noticed that some variable on that page are tagged as "(not available during `<If>`)" but there's no such designation on the time variables

I am using Apache 2.4.41 which (as far as I can tell) should be sufficient to have all of this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`Header always set Attention "expr=you are using still using IPV4 in %{TIME_YEAR}, please blahblah etc"`